# ExcelVBA-Time Delay: How to use Time Delay after running macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to use time delays in Excel VBA.

Here's what I want to do:

I have a button in macro that when I click it, it sends the first email. Then after 1 hour, I want to automatically send the second email without clicking another button or running the program again.

I have this code that will set the time. Then after the time expires, it will run the macro. What I want do is to automatically send the second email in an hour after the first send off.

```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     Dim sSetTimer As Date

     sSetTimer = Sheets("SetTime").Cells(1, 1)

     Application.OnTime TimeValue(sSetTimer), "Orayt"

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an hour to the first time and use it to launch a secondary process.

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue(sSetTimer), "Orayt"
Application.OnTime TimeValue(sSetTimer) + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0), "Orayt2"
```