# is it possible to run a sub from a template sheet? if so how?

Tags: excel, vba

so I have a workbook where a user selects how many working days are in each week. This workbook is opened from a template. when the user has to change the amount of working days there is in a week I want to update the template worksheet so the next time the template is used the user doesn't have to go back through the process again. to achieve this I have added a 'save as' bit of code to overwrite the old template. I then open an intermediary sheet to close the first book after it has saved itself. this intermediary then opens a new workbook based off the newly saved template. I then want to run one of the macros in the template workbook. however as the .run command opens a workbook and not a template I cannot use this. is there another way around it? or is there a way to open the template and use the run command at the same time?

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Y:\RUN ORDER\TEMPLATES\POSITION TEMPLATE.XLSM", FileFormat:=52

Application.Run "'Y:\RUN ORDER\TEMPLATES\TEMP P+T.XLSM'!MIDDLEMAN"

End Sub
```

the above code is from the first template sheet as it is saving itself and then running the sub in the intermediary sheet

the below code is what I have in the intermediary sheet

```
Sub MIDDLEMAN()

Windows("POSITION TEMPLATE.XLSM").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Workbooks.Add TEMPLATE:="Y:\RUN ORDER\TEMPLATES\POSITION TEMPLATE.xlsm"

Application.Run "'Y:\RUN ORDER\TEMPLATES\POSITION TEMPLATE1'!TRANSFERDATES"

End Sub
```

obviously the middleman sub falls down when it tries to run the macro as it cannot find a sheet called position template1 as it doesn't get saved and so doesn't exist. position template1 is the name given to the workbook created from the template. i have also tried

```
application.run template:="'Y:\RUN ORDER\TEMPLATES\POSITION TEMPLATE1'!TRANSFERDATES"
```

but it comes up with an error on the template part saying named argument not found.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If I read it right, you want a sub to be run from the template files as you open them, i.e. have `transferdates` and `middleman` in their respective `Workbook_Open` event?

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes, I've been trying to activate them from the previous workbook as I am not to sure how to do open events but that seems like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if I followed all the logic correctly but something like this is probably what you're going for:

Step1:

```
'Workbook1 opens the template file to choose dates
Sub copyTemplate()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'for the overwriting prompt
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Y:\RUN ORDER\TEMPLATES\POSITION TEMPLATE.XLSM", FileFormat:=52
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Workbooks.Open "Y:\RUN ORDER\TEMPLATES\TEMP P+T.XLSM"
End Sub
```

Step2:

```
'Workbook2 -template, has button to finish up after date-picking
Sub button1_Click()
    'finishing up, overwrites or saveas main template for that person
    'your pick
    'closes itself
End Sub
```

Step3:

```
'Workbook1
Sub openTemplate()
    'opens the new and improved template
    'assign this to another button? Again, your choice
    'run the copy-date-macro in the new and improved workbook2
End Sub
```

Step4:

```
'Better_Workbook2
'this could technically be done together with step3 unless there's some more logic 
'as to why the user has to start the calculations
Sub button2_Click()
    'calculation and creation of workbook4
    'closes itself without saving
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I will just use the method you used on the first one for both sheets as I don't want to save the template as position template1. after that sheet does what it needs to it creates another sheet and the closes without saving ill have aa test and let you know if it works.

Comment: for some reason they aren't running the macros fully when the sheets open. the temp p+t closes the position template sheet but doesn't then open the template again and the same thing happens with the template sheet it closes the temp p+t but then doesn't run the rest of the sub :/

Comment: See it as parentheses: Workbookcode1_OpenOtherFile(WorkbookCode2_OtherFile(close workbook1)), if you tell the inner code to close the workbook that opened the file your current code is running in, it makes sense that the rest of the sub stops, no? Fyi, Sheets are not workbooks, please try to differentiate them :)

Comment: so would there be a way to get around that? e.g. in the middleman sub which is triggered by the workbook opening. it stops after closing position template but I would like it to run the workbooks .add bit as well.

Comment: Try explaining the full hurdle, please, from the start. User opens a management workbook called Workbook1, in there they select the days or does workbook1 load the workbook (workbook2) from a template (workbook3) which gets edited if they change anything in workbook2 -> workbook2 gets saved as workbook3. After the template gets overwritten, what needs to happen...? Also, I don't see how you call it a template if it's simply overwritten if they change something to it.

Comment: the date part of it only gets updated once a quarter or so. the template workbook also creates another workbook and then closes itself after creating that workbook (it uses the dates list as a reference for calculations). wb1 creates wb2 from a template. wb2 has the dates list in it. user sets dates. then generates the dates list. wb2 overwrites template used to make itself then opens wb3. wb3 closes wb2 then creates wb2 from template (now with updated dates) wb2 closes wb3 and runs sub to copy dates to other 2 sheets in wb2 user then presses button wb2 calculates then creates and saves wb4

Comment: wb2 then closes itself without saving. the hang up is when wb3 is opened, it closes wb2 (like it should) but then doesn't create the new wb2 from the template if I can get wb3 to automatically create wb2 from the template after closing wb2 the it will work fully, I did as you suggested and tagged the sub to the open event of wb3 but as you said above it is stopping the code after closing wb2 (i hope this makes sense)

Comment: Why don't you just cut out the middle man? Just edit the template, after saving it with the updated dates, continue with rest of code, i.e. creating/saving wb4 (after creating and transferring data to wb4, you can close wb2 without saving)

Comment: as this is a sheet that will be used my multiple people that are not technically minded I don't want them to have the ability to save it even by accident so that is why I am trying to not use the saved template to create the new sheet

Comment: Made an edit to my answer, hopefully the logic fits more your scenario and you can get it to work this way.

Comment: so in the end I relented and added a button to workbook 3 instead of having it be an open event. id still like to find a way to make it automatic without stopping because of closing the previous sheet. I see what you was getting at but I wanted to avoid going back to workbook 1 as the user may think that it hasn't worked/ has already created the new sheet when it hasn't. I used the open events on wb2 though to do a couple of things including closing wb3 so thanks for the suggestion on that.

Comment: You can always give the user a MsgBox to indicate what has (not) happened/what they still have to do.

Comment: While on a project, it just dawned on me that there is such a thing as telling a macro to run after a delay which would allow your code to finish, close up the one that you started with and then have the macro run after said delay. [Like in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324351/excelvba-time-delay-how-to-use-time-delay-after-running-macro) no promises that it'll work for you but it's worth a try? @Seb358